# Is it possible to tell sed to perform a maximum of one substitution command per line?

Tags: sed, substitution

Is it possible to encapsulate the following pseudocode using sed?

```
for line in lines:
    if line == "foo":
        print "FOO"
    else:
        print "- " + line
```

Here's the first thing I tried:

```
> echo 'foo
> bar
> baz' | sed -e 's/^foo$/FOO/' -e 's/^/- /'
- FOO
- bar
- baz
```

This is incorrect since *both* substitutions are applied to the first line.

Is it possible to tell sed to perform a maximum of one substitution per line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit what lines a substitution affects, by prefixing it with a pattern:

```
sed -e '/^foo$/! s/^/- /' -e '/^foo$/ s//FOO/' infile
```

A better alternative is to use the `t` branch command which will go to the next line if the previous substitution succeeded:

```
sed 's/^foo$/FOO/; t; s/^/- /' infile
```

Or the more portable:

```
sed -e 's/^foo$/FOO/' -e t -e 's/^/- /' infile
```

Output in both cases:

```
FOO
- bar
- baz
```

Comment: When I run this on OS X I get an "undefined label" error. Perhaps `t` is not supported on OS X.

Comment: @davidchambers: I've added a more portable version which should work.